# How to add a checkbox to form builder component settings form?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and [formbuilder](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_builder) modules installed.

In the file field settings form I want to add an extra checkbox field just like the required field but I am unable to do that.

I can add it to the `webform_component_edit_form` like the following

```
$form['validation']['check'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Check'),
      '#default_value' => ($component['check'] == '1' ? TRUE : FALSE),
      '#description' => t('Check this option if the user should be able to upload files.'),
      '#weight' => -1,
      '#parents' => array('check'),
    );
```

But it is not displaying in the `formbuilder` file settings edit form `form_builder_field_configure`.

Is there any way to add a field to `form_builder_field_configure` form and save with the node just like other fields?

Comment: Install File Entity module then create a field checkbox type like alt text.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it inside the form_id 'form_builder_field_configure'.
Example :

```
hook_form_alter($form,$form_state,$form_id){
`switch($form_id){
     case 'form_builder_field_configure':
     // You put your code here
     $form['check'] = array(
       '#form_builder' => array(
         'property_group' => 'validation'
       ),
       '#type' => 'checkbox',
       '#title' => t('Check'),
       '#default_value' => '',
       '#description' => t('Check this option if the user should be able 
    to upload 
     files.'),
      '#weight' => -1,
);
  break;
 }
```

}
     `

I hope it'll help you.